# How to run a script to get certain contents of a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

So say a file has the login data for a bunch of users:

```
bobby activityname 2014-05-12(bobbymiller@gmail.com)
bill activityname 2014-06-12(bobbymiller@gmail.com)
bobby activityname 2014-06-12(bobbymiller@gmail.com)
```

How can I make a script to make a cew file that shows the person name and the different dates they logged in?

```
bill
2014-06-12
bobby
2014-05-12 
2014-06-12
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F'[ (]' '{a[$1]=a[$1] $3 "\n"} END{for (name in a)print name "\n" a[name]}' loginFile
bobby
2014-05-12
2014-06-12

bill
2014-06-12
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[ (]'`

  This tells `awk` to accept either a space or an open parens as the field separator.
- `a[$1]=a[$1] $3 "\n"`

  This stores the login dates for each user in an array `a`.
- `END{for (name in a)print name "\n" a[name]}`

  When we have finished reading the file, this prints out the collected data.

#### Saving output to a file

To save the output to a file, one can use shell *redirection*. Thus:

```
awk -F'[ (]' '{a[$1]=a[$1] $3 "\n"} END{for (name in a)print name "\n" a[name]}' loginFile >newFile
```

#### Handling a date *and* a time

Suppose that the input file looks like:

```
$ cat loginFile2 
bobby activityname 2014-05-12 15:20(bobbymiller@gmail.com)
```

To get date and time, run:

```
$ awk -F'[ (]' '{a[$1]=a[$1] $3 " " $4 "\n"} END{for (name in a)print name "\n" a[name]}' loginFile2
bobby
2014-05-12 15:20
```

#### Handling multiple spaces

The above examples all had single spaces.  If there may be one or more spaces between items, then, for files with date *and* time, use:

```
awk -F' *[ (]' '{a[$1]=a[$1] $3 " " $4 "\n"} END{for (name in a)print name "\n" a[name]}' loginFile
```

Comment: what about the file names?? say my original file with all the data is called loginFile and i want to put the print results in a new file called newFile

Comment: @Youngle OK. I just added an example that reads from `loginFile` and writes the output to `newFile`.

Comment: on the original file if it was bobby activityname 2014-05-12 15:20(bobbymiller@gmail.com) instead and you wanted to print bobby
2014-05-12 15:27 how would that change the program since there is a space between the date and the time? how can you put the date and time together in the array?

Comment: @Youngle I added a section on how to handle date and time.

Comment: what if the number of spaces vary depending on the length of the name?

Comment: @Youngle I added section with code to handle multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one through python.

```
import sys
import re
from collections import defaultdict
file = sys.argv[1]
f = open(file, 'r')
m = re.findall(r'(?m)^(\S+).*?\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?=\()', f.read())
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in m:
    d[k].append(v)
result = dict(d.items())
for i in result:
    print(i)
    print('\n'.join([x for x in result[i]]))
    print('\n', end = "")
```

Save the above script to a file, say `script.py` and then run script against the input file by firing the below command on the terminal.

```
python3 script.py inputfile
```